# How to customize Thelia template with less?

Tags: compiler-construction, less, webstorm

I imported the project into WebStorm 8 but when I try to change vales into .less files WebStorm give me this error:

```
/usr/local/bin/lessc --no-color import.less
NameError: variable @screen-desktop is undefined in
/Users/iulianrusu/Sites/thelia/templates/frontOffice/default/assets/less/thelia/variables.less
on line 11, column 37: 10 // Grid system 11 @grid-float-breakpoint:
@screen-desktop; 12 Process finished with exit code 2
```

Does anybody know the easier way to modify the default theme?

Comment: the error comes from LESS compiler, not from WebStorm. Is @screen-desktop variable defined anywhere in your .less files?

Comment: There is no @screen-desktop into less files.

Answer (score 2):

First, `@screen-desktop` is defined in assets/less/bootstrap/variables.less :

```
@screen-md:                  992px;
@screen-desktop:             @screen-md;
```

Next, you should recompile assets\less\style.css only, not every LESS files individually. Configure your IDE according to this.

The easiest way to quickly customize the default template is in the assets/themes/default/less files, which controls colors and styles of the theme.