# How are less files compiled into css templates in PHP Thelia?

Tags: php, css, symfony, templates, less

When using Thelia (http://thelia.net/) which is built on the symfony 2 framework, the developers provide a less templating system for creating themes or altering variables in the default template. I can see it boils down to one file styles.less which calls all the others, and I can see the minified styles.css which the less file should compile into. But nowhere in the documentation do they specify how to compile this file.

I have found this:

http://doc.thelia.net/en/documentation/templates/assets.html
Which suggests to set automatic asset generation to 1 (which I have done and cleared the cache with no evident recompile.

I have also found this:

[How to customize Thelia template with less?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312741/how-to-customize-thelia-template-with-less)
Which tells me to modify the files I am modifying, but now how to compile them into the minified css.

Searching google reveals a few different projects for external less compilers in php, but considering the nature of the symfony 2 based command structure of the thelia project I cant help thinking Im missing something inbuilt to recompile these assets. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: For anyone else having any issues with this, it turns out the inbuilt less compiler (leafo/lessphp v0.4.0) is incompatible with the included version of bootstrap less and was failing to compile. I used composer to install less.php (http://lessphp.gpeasy.com/) and used the command line tool lessc to correctly compile styles.less to styles.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to compile less in Thelia you have to use grunt to compile and bower to get dependencies.
There are some task preconfigured to compile all less and js files.

Just follow the doc :

- [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started)
- [bower](http://bower.io/)

After install you just have to go in your template directory and use the command grunt.

Comment: Why would I want to use grunt when the Thelia package does not include or require NodeJS, I am not programming in NodeJS, but the grunt homepage states - 

"Grunt and Grunt plugins are installed and managed via npm, the Node.js package manager. Grunt 0.4.x requires stable Node.js versions >= 0.8.0."

Comment: Because it's an easy way to customise Thelia template. Grunt and bower files are prepared. You just have to use them even there is no depency with  NodeJS  in Thelia package.

Comment: Thankyou for that info, only just noticed and now marked as most helpful answer.